# Java: how to match a string like this "<jms:reference-file*</jms:reference-file>"

Tags: java, regex, phpstorm

I have to remove a string like the following:

```
<jms:reference-file line="12">/../src/AppBundle/Resources/views/ControllerName/template_name.html.twig</jms:reference-file>
```

I have many files and I'd like to use the regular expression match provided by the PHPStorm editor.

Unfortunately I don't know Java and the editor required Java regular expressions.

I'm not so good with regular expressions in general but I think that matching this string is something not so hard...

Is there someone who can help me match all the strings like this in all files?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Did you see the most voted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, using this tool http://regex.inginf.units.it/ (with small adjustments on my side) I finally get the regex that is this:

```
<jms:reference-file [^ ]++
```